# Excel - coloured bars in bar chart based on value

Tags: excel, bar-chart

I've got a table like below:

[image]

And chart made from this table:

[image]

Now i would like to format the color of bars in this chart based on whether the value is >=100% (then green color) or <100%.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far?

Comment: Only thing that i found is that I need to add one more row to 1st and 2nd and then if the value is greater than 100% it will be in upper cell, in opposite way in cell below, this works, but then there are some free spaces between 1st and 2nd bar and I would like to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

You could use VBA to reformat the bars, based on the values:

```
Sub BarChartConditionalFormat()
    Dim ser As Series
    Dim v() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
        For Each ser In .SeriesCollection
            v = ser.Values
            For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
                If v(i) >= 1 Then
                    ser.Points(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                Else
                    ser.Points(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ser.Format.Fill.ForeColor
                End If
            Next i
        Next ser
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot! :)